# BeautifulSoup isn't getting the full Image Address

Tags: python, html, web, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Im using beautiful soup to scrape images from a website, however my code isn't returning the full address of the image that is visible when inspecting the webpage.

```
for b in soup.select(".thumb_div.clear a"):
            imagelink = a["href"].replace("/mushrooms/", "http://www.foragingguide.com/mushrooms/")
            print(imagelink)
```

Should return : `http://static.foragingguide.com/photos/mushrooms/amethyst_deceiver/87.jpg`
as the source code is:

```
<a href="http://static.foragingguide.com/photos/mushrooms/amethyst_deceiver/87.jpg" rel="lightbox[photos]" title="Amethyst Deceiver (Laccaria amethystina)">
```

But instead just returns `http://static.foragingguide.com/photos/mushrooms/amethyst_deceiver/` without the jpg file ending which is necessary for this to work.

does anyone know why this is?
thanks.

Comment: Why do you need to replace ? Aren't the links absolute ?

Comment: It does not return an absolute link, just a relative path, hence why I’ve done a replace

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Simple solution"

```
for b in soup.select(".thumb_div a"):
            imagelink = b["href"]
            print(imagelink)
```

turns out the "a" in a["href"] is nothing to do with , it is "a" the iterable, which doesn't exist. changing the code to b["href"] works.

Answer (score 2):

You don't really have to do a replacement, just target the image source directly.

For example:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


end_point = "http://www.foragingguide.com/mushrooms/sp/amethyst_deceiver"
response = requests.get(end_point).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(response, "lxml").select(".thumb_div a")
print("\n".join(i["href"] for i in soup))
```

Output:

```
http://static.foragingguide.com/photos/mushrooms/amethyst_deceiver/87.jpg
http://static.foragingguide.com/photos/mushrooms/amethyst_deceiver/88.jpg
http://static.foragingguide.com/photos/mushrooms/amethyst_deceiver/90.jpg
http://static.foragingguide.com/photos/mushrooms/amethyst_deceiver/91.jpg
```

Comment: great solution, however I am trying to get the paths to the regular images, not the thumbnails, Can I follow the same procedure to get the regular image linked in the a tags?